# Azure Function Servicebus batch process messages - python

Tags: python, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am implementing an azure function in python which is trying to batch process messages from a servicebus queue. I have modified the host.json file as follows:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "serviceBus": {
        "batchOptions": {
            "maxMessageCount": 20,
            "operationTimeout": "01:00:00",
            "autoComplete": true
        }
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
    }
}
```

However, I am a bit lost as to how the messages will be received in my entry function in `__init__.py`. Will it just be a list of messages and I can just loop through the messages as follows:

```py
def main(messages: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    for msg in messages:
        json_obj = json.loads(msg.get_body().decode("utf-8"))
        print(json_obj)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't see its possible to process batch messages at once. You can configure the max_concurrent_calls in the `host.json` file. AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__serviceBus__messageHandlerOptions__maxConcurrentCalls can be set to any number(10) to override the settings from the environment settings. Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values

Answer (score 0):

Your binding configuration is not right, it is to be done in *function.json* properly. After your Azure function is configured as a Service Bus trigger, and bound correctly to the queue, then for *each* message generated, your function will get invoked *once*. Your function will not *get* array of messages. See the example code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python) to get more details.

Instead of a service bus Queue trigger, if you need your function app to process bunch of service bus messages, then you need to connect to the Service Bus Client and then receive the messages, see the code in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues) page.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is clearly asked - how do you invoke and process messages in batches with service bus queue triggered python function app? For C# version, there seems to be a property to configure i.e. IsBatched, however it is not there for python version.
Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes

Comment: In my answer, I have stated that "each" message will be passed to the function, it will _not_ get an array of messages - because for Python based Service Bus sdk it is not supported at present.

Comment: Haven't tried yet but something that is worth looking at - Enable service bus batch trigger (cardinality=many)
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library/pull/73